# Flutter - CircularProgressIndicator max value

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to find a way to change max value of CircularProgressIndicator

```
child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 10,
                                value: math().valuePercentage,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 152, 152),
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 54, 54),
```

i was trying to do it with some math, but i stuck on this:

```
class math {
  double valuePercentage = kcalData().Target / 10000;
}
```

for example, we have 3216 kcal and the maximum of CircularProgressIndicator is 1.0, so i decide to devide kcal value by 10000, but i want to make a maximum from my Target value. I'm bad at math, so maybe some of you can get it...
Any ideas? Or maybe there is another way to do this?

edit: maximum of indicator equals 1.0, can't set no more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value: currentValue / totalValue,
```

**currentValue**: value which you want to show on your indicator

**totalValue**: max value of your progressIndicator

Comment: But this is what i do here. totalValue can be 100, 200, 1000 or 15354 as max value. You can define it as you wish. currentValue is the progress you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your target 10000. This is the maximum. If you want to find how much is the percentage of 3126 in relation with 10000, then you have to divide 3126 with 10000. If you want to have a different max every time, then divide your value with your max.